# Good practice for JSON error response for 400 and 500

Tags: json, rest

I have read many RESTful API design pattern resources.
But I'm not confident for deciding API.

It seems there does not not exist a standard JSON response format.
I need advice for my Json error response as below.

`401`
jwt token related fail

```
{
  code:1,
  message: "no access token"
}

{
  code:2,
  message: "invalid access token"
}

{
  code:3,
  message: "expired access token"
}
```

`400`
client's insufficient input parameter

```
{
  code:20,
  message: "input paramter 'search' is missing"
}
```

client's invalid value request

```
{
  code:21,
  message: "invalid serial no"
}
```

client's invalid request format

```
{
  code:22,
  message: "input parameter indate is invalid date format"
}
```

`500`
another mesh-up server's problem

```
{
  code:30,
  message: "no reply from external server API"
}
```

program logic error (ex. exception)

```
{
  code:31,
  message: "internal server error"
}
```

For 500 cases, I think client also needs more information.
And another concern is "Is error code needed?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **Problem Details for HTTP APIs**.

It's a nice format that can be extended easily to provide the client a good way to react on each error/problem appropriately.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807

Here is an example taken from the RFC:

```
{
  "type": "https://example.com/probs/out-of-credit",
  "title": "You do not have enough credit.",
  "detail": "Your current balance is 30, but that costs 50.",
  "instance": "/account/12345/msgs/abc",
  "balance": 30,
  "accounts": ["/account/12345", "/account/67890"]
}
```